# Solution of system of ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let $x$ and $y$ be continuously differentiable functions on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying the following differential equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt}+(\sin(t)-1)x=\log(1+t),\;x(0)=1$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+(\sin(t)-1)y=t,\;y(0)=2$$

Define $z(t)=y(t)-x(t),t\geq 0$. Which of the following statements are true ?

$1.$ $z(t)\leq 1$.

$2.$ $z(2)>z(1)$.

$3.$ $z(1)>1$.

$4.$ $z(2)\leq z(1).$

Firstly I thought to apply the Sturm comparison theorem but it’s for homogeneous differential equations. Secondly I thought that $z$ is solution of the differential equation $$\frac{dz}{dt}+(\sin(t)-1)z=\log(1+t)-t,\;z(0)=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, your DE for $z$ is correct. The resulting DE is first-order linear:
\begin{align*}
\dot{z}+\underbrace{(\sin(t)-1)}_{p(t)}z&=\ln(1+t)-t\\
e^{\int p(t)\,dt}&=e^{-\cos(t)-t}=\text{integrating factor}\\
e^{-\cos(t)-t}\dot{z}+e^{-\cos(t)-t}(\sin(t)-1)z&=e^{-\cos(t)-t}[\ln(1+t)-t]\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{-\cos(t)-t}\,z\right]&=e^{-\cos(t)-t}[\ln(1+t)-t]\\
e^{-\cos(t)-t}\,z(t)-e^{-1}&=\int_0^t e^{-\cos(\tau)-\tau}[\ln(1+\tau)-\tau]\,d\tau\\
e^{-\cos(t)-t}\,z(t)&=e^{-1}+\int_0^t e^{-\cos(\tau)-\tau}[\ln(1+\tau)-\tau]\,d\tau\\
z(t)&=e^{\cos(t)+t-1}+e^{\cos(t)+t}\int_0^t e^{-\cos(\tau)-\tau}[\ln(1+\tau)-\tau]\,d\tau\\
&=e^{\cos(t)+t-1}\left[1+e\int_0^t e^{-\cos(\tau)-\tau}[\ln(1+\tau)-\tau]\,d\tau\right]
\end{align*}
The integral on the RHS is intractable, but there are some things we can say about $z(t)$ qualitatively from this expression. First, the integrand is non-positive, which implies that the integral is non-positive. If $t=0,$ the integral is zero, of course, making $z(0)=1,$ as required. As $t$ increases, the integral will become more negative, eventually overcoming the $1.$ The option 1 is false: $z$ definitely gets bigger than $1.$ Option 2 is also false. You can approximate $z(2)\approx 1.06518,$ whereas $z(1)\approx 1.59294.$ By the same token, Option 3 is true, and if Option 2 is false, which it is, then Option 4, being its negation, must be true. Hence, we conclude that Options 3 and 4 are true.

[EDIT] Here is some Mathematica code to plot this function:

```
g[t_]:=Exp[Cos[t]+t-1](1+Exp[1]NIntegrate[Exp[-Cos[s]-s](Log[1+s]-s),{s,0,t}])
Plot[g[t],{t,0,5}]
```

with the results:

[image]

So we can see that the function starts increasing, but then decreases. If we go further out:

```
Plot[g[t],{t,0,10}]
```

we get

[image]

So it appears that eventually, the function is always decreasing.

Comment: Thank you sir for giving solution. Sir you write solution will be more negative. I think solution will be increasing?

Comment: It starts increasing, with a maximum around $1,$ but then decreases, apparently monotonically.

Comment: Thank you sir . Actually sir it’s objective question and have to solved in limited time around $5$-minute . Can it be given in short time ?

Comment: @neelkanth I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking. Can you please clarify?

Comment: in answer key answer is given second and third options.

Comment: sir I want to say that in this question I have to solve it without any computer and I have to solve it within $5$ minutes of time . So is there any other short method to solve it ?

Comment: Well, I would say your answer key is wrong. My solution to the DE is correct, as can be verified by differentiating and plugging back into the DE and the initial condition. By uniqueness theorems, it is the only solution. Having to do this problem in 5 minutes is kind of ludicrous, to my mind. There might well be other methods of solution: in that case please talk with your teacher.

Comment: in question I did a mistake there should be $t-log(1+t)$.

Comment: @neelkanth It doesn't actually matter, because you "made the same mistake" on both sides of the DE.